# What are spatially extended systems?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, definition, complex-systems

i am reading about coupled map lattice and stuck on what exactly is the meaning of spatially extended systems. Please help.

Comment: All systems not assumed to be localized at a point.

Comment: Can u please elaborate or suggest any online resource where i could find more about this?

Comment: See http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Coupled_maps and http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?Location=U2&doc=GetTRDoc.pdf&AD=ADA468189

Answer (score -1):

I think it is similar to a thermal bath or environment which is not of interest but still important since it will interact with the system of interest.Typically the extended system is assumed to be harmonic oscillators.